# On connection.open program immediately throws error code 10054 (Connection forcibly closed)

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception, database-connection

Using Visual Studio 2017 (C# Project) & SQL Server 2016

Not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong. I've stripped down my entire method to just this code. The moment `connection.Open` is called I instantly get this exception:

**(10054) An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host**

```
try
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source = DEVELOPMENTBOX\\GAMEDATABASE; Initial Catalog = ItemDB; User ID = dataReader; Password = ********");
    connection.Open();
    System.Console.WriteLine("Succcess");
    connection.Close();
}
catch (System.Exception e)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Things I've checked:

- I am properly including `using System.Data.SqlClient`.
- Allow remote connections to this server is checked and timeout is 600.
- Protocols for GAMEDATABASE (Named Pipes, TCP/IP) are enabled.
- I can ping Development box via IP and hostname.
- Database security is set to SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode.
- Firewalls on both computers are disabled.
- Triple checked my username and password.
- Experimented with alternative connections strings via [www.connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com).

Things Of Note:

The DevelopmentBox is a machine on my local network. Also, if I attempt to use the built-in Visual Studio Server Explorer, after connecting to the Database and clicking the table folder, I get the following error thrown at me.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4y0ug.png)

> Failed to retrieve data for this request.
>
> Failed to connect to server (local).
>
> Login failed for user 'dataReader'.

I'm at such a loss. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you read https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187005(v=sql.105).aspx and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2008/04/08/understanding-connection-forcibly-closed-by-remote-host-errors-caused-by-toechimney/ ?

Comment: Your first link gave me the idea that maybe mono doesn't support MSSQL 2016 and looking at the System.Data.SqlClient.dll only goes up to 2008. http://www.mono-project.com/docs/database-access/providers/sqlclient/ Does this sound, right? Feel like that's pretty significant that it doesn't support anything past '08.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the user exists and the password is correct?

Comment: First removed datasource since the source is already specified in the initial catalog Initial Catalog = ItemDB and is redundant.  User and password don't usually work because of windows users accounts.  A window PC won't allow remote connections unless it is setup for a guest account or the remote computer is in a user group.  Better to use SQL Server Windows Group Account for credentials and put users into a group account.  Remote users to be able to access the database has to have an account or the client pc and the server pc and both pc's have to be in the same group.

Comment: Anything of interest in the SQL Server error log?

Answer (score 0):

After looking through the links **mjwills** posted. I found that my issue lies with the version of Mono I am using.

The most recent version, at the time of this post, only supports SQL Server 2008. When I took the exact same code above and pasted it into a new project using the .NET 4.7 library, it worked perfectly.

So thank you to mjwills for posting that article, would've never have though to look at the supported systems otherwise.

@mjwills. I'd like to give you credit but I can't mark comments as answers!